# insert into std::map using class method

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, stl, this

I searched a lot for this issue, but didn't find anything, so sorry if it's duplicate.

I have a problem with inserting into std::map using class method which returns ***this**. If i try to insert more values, only the first one is actually inserted. Let me show you my code:

```
using namespace std;

class test{
public:
   test(){}
   test Add(const int &a, const  int &b);
   void print(){
    for (auto it = map1.begin(); it != map1.end(); ++it) {
        cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    }
}

private:
   map<int,int> map1;

};

test test::Add(const int &a, const int &b) {

map1.insert(make_pair(a,b));

return *this;

}
```

But when i try something like this:

```
int main ( void ) {

test a;

a.Add(1,5) . Add( 4, 8);

a.print();

return 0;
}
```

only the first value is inserted into the map. What should i change to insert into map this way?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is that

```
test Add(const int &a, const  int &b);
```

returns by value.  That means the `test` returned from `Add` is not the same `test` you called it on, it is a copy.  That means when you do something like

```
a.Add(1,5) . Add( 4, 8);
```

the `. Add( 4, 8)` parts adds the item to a copy of `a` and not `a` itself.

The way you fix this is to return by reference instead of value.  When you return by reference you will be working with the item you called `add` on instead of a copy.  That means you just need to change the function signature to

```
test& Add(const int &a, const  int &b)
```

For both the declaration and the definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It fixed the problem.

Comment: @Cart No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you insert once is because your `Add` method returns by value and your second `. Add( 4, 8);` ends up inserting into another map. To fix this, you need to change your `Add` to return reference to `*this`:

```
using namespace std;

class test
{
public:
    test() {}
    test& Add(const int &a, const  int &b); // < -- changed to return test&
    void print() {
        for (auto it = map1.begin(); it != map1.end(); ++it) {
            cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    map<int, int> map1;
};

test& test::Add(const int &a, const int &b) // < -- changed to return test&
{
    map1.insert(make_pair(a, b));
    return *this;
}
```

[Output of your program with the fix](https://ideone.com/SiJ1vD) becomes:

```
1 5
4 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Add` function is returning a *copy* of the current object. To return the current object itself, you need to change the return type to a reference:

```
test & test::Add(const int &a, const int &b) {
// ^^^^^
  map1.insert(make_pair(a,b));
  return *this;
}
```

Your current code applies the second `Add` to a different object from the one the first `Add` is applied to, so you never see the effect. However, for laughs and giggles, you could also try:

```
a.Add(1,5) . Add( 4, 8) . print();
```